# Sidebar animation keeps playing on load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Have a sidebar on my website but when I load the page it plays the animation of it closing. how would I stop this?

I have a class #sidebar thats the class in its normal state and a class active that makes it move out

```
#sidebar {
   margin-left: -250px;
   width: 250px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100vh;
   z-index: 0;
   background: #222222;
   color: #fff;
   transition:  0.3s;
   visibility: hidden;
}

#sidebar.active {
   width: 250px;
   margin-left: 0px;
   transition:  0.3s;
   z-index: 999;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Javascript for changing the active class

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
            theme: "minimal"
        });

        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar, #content').toggleClass('active');
            $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
            $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
        });
    });
```

UPDATE

Html code for the sidebar. if it helps I am using mustache js for templating if that is of importance to this

```
<!-- Sidebar  -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>Admin Panel</h3>
        </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <p>Admin controls</p>
            <li>
                <a href="#menuSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu's</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="menuSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/newMenu">Add</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#catSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Categories</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="catSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/newCat">Add</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                            <li>
                <a href="#dishSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Dish's</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="dishSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/newDish">Add</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#staffSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Staff</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="staffSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Delete</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Site settings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="logout" href="/logout" class="btn btn-primary">Sign out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Could you also supply the HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below CSS

```
#sidebar {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: -250px;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 250px;
   height: 100vh;
   z-index: 999;
   background: #222222;
   color: #fff;
   transition: 0.3s;
 }

 #sidebar.active {
    left: 0;
 }
```

Plus you have to pass active class to your sidebar also if you want to be active by default

```
<nav id="sidebar" class="active">
```